# Binary Search Tree select method implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm currently going over [Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms book](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/). In the book I'm trying to understand the implementation of the `select` method in a Binary Search Tree. The author uses a BST to implement a symbol table. The author describes the `select` method as follow:

> Suppose that we seek the key of rank k (the key such that precisely k
> other keys in the BST are smaller). If the number of keys t in the
> left sub- tree is larger than k, we look (recursively) for the key of
> rank k in the left subtree; if t is equal to k, we return the key at
> the root; and if t is smaller than k, we look (recursively) for the
> key of rank k - t - 1 in the right subtree. As usual, this de-
> scription serves both as the basis for the recursive select() method
> on the facing page and for a proof by induction that it works as
> expected.

I want to understand specifically what is the purpose of the `k - t - 1` pass to the recursive select method when the size of the left node is less than the number of keys smaller than `k`.

```
 public Key select(int k)
  {
     return select(root, k).key;
  }

  private Node select(Node x, int k)
  {   // Return Node containing key of rank k.
      if (x == null) return null;
      int t = size(x.left);
      if      (t > k) return select(x.left,  k);
      else if (t < k) return select(x.right, k-t-1);
      else            return x;
}
```

As you can see the above implementation of the `select` method of a Binary Search Tree. When the conditional `t < k` the author passes `k-t-1` to the recursive `select` method call but I can't still figure out why that is.

[image]

Comment: I would also recommend reviewing the source code of [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) for one particular example of an implementation. It's quite good.

Answer (score 3):

k − t − 1 is equal to k − (t + 1). When t < k and we recurse into the right subtree, the t elements in the left subtree and the 1 root count toward the rank of the elements in the right subtree, so we need to adjust k to match.

Comment: Then, Why root is returned when t == k if the rank of the root is k+1?

Comment: @YashShah 0-based indexing.